# The Default Dataform SA unable to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION

Tags: google-dataform

I followed the Google's documentation on granting necessary permissions for Dataform SAs:

- BigQuery Data Editor on projects to which Dataform needs both read
  and write access. They usually include the project hosting your
  Dataform repository.
- BigQuery Data Viewer on projects to whichDataform needs read only access.
- BigQuery Job User on the project hosting your Dataform repository.
- BigQuery Data Owner if you want to query BigQuery datasets.
- roles/bigquery.resourceViewer

I am still getting an access error when I try to execute the workflow. Could anyone please tell me why I am getting the error?